# How can I put 2 links into 1 image in Markdown

Tags: html, image, hyperlink, markdown, zendesk

I want to put 2 links into 1 image. I did for 1 links here is a example: `[![](image.png)](link-url)` but it's not enough actually

Comment: if you place two links in one image what is suppose to happen when you click on the image?

Comment: Second link need to open in new tab

Comment: You want an [HTML image map](https://html.com/images/how-to-make-an-image-map/). Markdown does not have native support for them. Therefore, you would need to embed raw HTML into your Markdown document.